# Flutter: animate text color

Tags: flutter, dart, text, flutter-animation

I am trying to animate some text in my flutter app so that each word's color changes, one after the other - kind of like in karaoke:

[image]

I've been looking at packages like animated_text_kit but so far have not found a ready-made solution for this. Maybe there is one out there?

If not, how might I go about making this animation? Making a custom animation for animated_text_kit maybe?

Ideally the amount of time each word is highlighted would depend on the length of the word, too.

Edit: here is what I am trying so far - not the intended effect though.

```dart
  Widget textAnimated() {
    TextStyle style = TextStyle(
        fontSize: 18,
        height: 3.0,
    return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10, top: 140),
        child: AnimatedTextKit(
          animatedTexts: [
            ColorizeAnimatedText("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.",
                textStyle: style, colors: [Colors.white, Colors.black])
          ],
        ));
  }
```

Comment: Can you include what you;ve tried so far?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh have done now, not sure it will help much though

Comment: The word will change color periodically ?

Comment: The effect I am looking for is for only one word to be visible at a time by changing the color of the text to either match the background color (white) or be visible (black). This should proceed from the first word in the text to the last.

Comment: can you include your desire output gif?

Comment: I've added that now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this widget

```dart
  MyAnimatedText(
            sentence: "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.",
          )
```

**MyAnimatedText** widget

```dart
class MyAnimatedText extends StatefulWidget {
  final String sentence;

  const MyAnimatedText({
    Key? key,
    required this.sentence,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyAnimatedText> createState() => _MyAnimatedTextState();
}

class _MyAnimatedTextState extends State<MyAnimatedText> {
  late List<String> words = widget.sentence.split(" ").toList();

  late Timer timer;

  int activeIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      activeIndex++;
      if (activeIndex > words.length) activeIndex = 0;
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        children: () {
          List<InlineSpan> spans = [];
          for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            spans.add(TextSpan(
              text: words[i] + " ",
              style: i == activeIndex
                  ? const TextStyle( //highlight style
                      color: Colors.orange,
                      fontSize: 24,
                    )
                  : TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                      fontSize: 24,
                    ),
            ));
          }
          return spans;
        }(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```